# Colocar botón a la derecha del navbar, pero a la izquierda en dispositivos móviles

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Estaba probando `bootstrap` y me he topado con esta situación: siguiendo con la demo de la documentación he intentado posicionar el botón de cerrar sesión a la **derecha** del `navbar` cuando la pantalla está maximizada (en caso de que el diseño sea responsive o la pantalla sea de x medida y se active el icon de menú debe estar a la izquierda el botón de cerrar sesión) pero por motivos que desconozco, no ha funcionado.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery cdn -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: white;">Home</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="background-color: white;">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="post" action="@Url.Action(" LogOff ", "Home ")">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Cerrar sesión</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Intenté añadiendo el atributo `style="float:right"` pero no he conseguido el resultado que esperaba, el botón siempre aparece a la izquierda. ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de hacerlo?

Posteriormente probé con estas dos opciones:

**Opción A:**

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" style="float:right;" method="post" action="@Url.Action("LogOff", "Home")">
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Cerrar sesión</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Opción B:**

Y aplicando el en el `<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"formjustify-content-end" etc>`

Si bien estas dos últimas opciones solucionan el problema al achicar la pantalla y mostrar el ícono del menú, el botón de cerrar sesión permanece a la derecha y en este caso quiero que esté a la izquierda.

Comment: ¿Te referís al botón de cerrar sesión o al _toggler_?

Comment: Al de cerrar sesión . Cando la pantalla del navegador esta en modo maximizar tamaño, debe estar a la derecha. Cuando se presiona minimizar tamaño o el diseño sea responsive debe estar a la izquierda debajo de home y se debe mostrar luego de presionado el toggler @padaleiana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sencillo: debés agregar la clase *ml-auto* al `form`:

Conviene que revises el apartado [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) en la documentación de Bootstrap.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery cdn -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: white;">Home</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="background-color: white;">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto" method="post" action="@Url.Action(" LogOff ", "Home ")">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Cerrar sesión</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<div class="div collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-lg-end justify-content-sm-start" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
     <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="post" action="@Url.Action(" LogOff ", "Home ")">
           <button class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Cerrar sesión</button>
     </form>
 </div>
```

Lo que hacemos es, decirle que el div contenedor que en lg se sitúe a la derecha *con justify-content-lg-end* mientras que en sm inclusive o menores, se situará a la izquierda.